# Watchkit, how to call a function from a view controller in the parent app

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I am pretty new to programming and completely self taught, so feel free to point out errors in logic or best practice.

I am trying to update a setting in the settingsViewController of the parent app with a toggle button in my watch app. If i use app groups and NSUserDefaults then i can get the settings to update whenever the settingsViewContoller appears by checking defaults. But i need the app to update live as the user toggles the switch in the watch app. I have tried using openParentApplication in the watchSettingsViewController.

```
- (IBAction)soundToggle:(BOOL)value {
if(!value){
    NSDictionary * soundToggleOff = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects: @[@"soundToggleOff"] forKeys: @[@"toggleState"]];

    [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:soundToggleOff reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Sound reply is %@", replyInfo );
    }];

}else{
    NSDictionary * soundToggleOn = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects: @[@"soundToggleOn"] forKeys: @[@"toggleState"]];

    [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:soundToggleOn reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Sound reply is %@", replyInfo );
    }];

}
```

Then in the appDelagate for the parent app I am using:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply{

    NSString * request = [userInfo objectForKey:@"toggleState"];
    NSString * notificationStatus = request;
    SettingsViewController * settingsView = [[SettingsViewController alloc]init];


    if ([request isEqualToString:@"soundToggleOn"]) {
        [settingsView updatePushNotificationSettings: settingsView.soundButton];

    }else if ([request isEqualToString:@"soundToggleOff"]){
        [settingsView updatePushNotificationSettings: settingsView.soundButton];

}

    NSDictionary * replyContent = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:@[notificationStatus] forKeys:@[@"notificationStatus"]];
    reply(replyContent);
}
```

But in the parent app the settings don't change. Is there a way to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to update a value in NSUserDefaults then I would not bother creating a view controller. Instead, I would just extract the settings saving functionality in a plain class and call its method to update the setting.

Answer (score 0):

In "application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:", you are creating a new "SettingsViewController" but never pushing it on screen.

If there is a "SettingsViewController" already on screen, you need to grab the reference to that one and update the "setting" in this view controller.